# How to send Image in android from my app to other app?

Tags: android-studio, android-implicit-intent

I wants to send an image stored in the drawable folder to some other app using ACTION_SEND ,my code is given below:

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.sendimage) { 
   Uri imageUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawable"+R.drawable.screen)‌​; 
    intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); intent.setType("image/*"); 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
    chooser=intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Image Via");
    startActivity(chooser);
 }
```

But when i try to send using button in my app  to Gmail a toast message "Can't attach empty file " appears and similar message also appear in other apps too while sending and some app even crashes.
So could you please help me in figuring out the mistake??

Comment: post code not image of code.

Comment: if(view.getId()==R.id.sendimage)
        {
            Uri imageUri =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawable"+R.drawable.screen);
            intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            chooser=intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Image Via");
            startActivity(chooser);
        }